# How to determine the radius of a circle from the scale of the sprite?

Tags: geometry, libgdx, scale

I am making this game where a sprite of a circle( origin set at the center of the sprite) is being up-scaled and rotated simultaneously. What I need to determine is the change in the radius of the circle in relation to scaling.How do I go about doing that? What exactly does scaling do? I mean what does 2x scale mean? does it mean my sprite has twice the area than previous?  Btw , I am using LibGDX.

Comment: Usually the scale factor refers to lengths, so a factor of 2 would mean twice the radius, and therefore four times the area.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.The problem was that the bounding rectangle of a sprite changes in size as the sprite is being rotated.So the raidous of the circle can not be determined using the with of the rectangle at that time. What I found was that the width of the bounding rectangle is the product of the scale and the initial width .So I can calculate what the width would be at any instance from that even if the sprite is rotating. And I get the radius from that.